# Unable to generate PDF in react native iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I inherited a legacy react-native legacy application that runs on iOS and Android. There is one section of code that generates the PDF report which I pasted below. The code works perfectly fine in Android but it hangs in iOS app.
Import functions :

```
import pdfmake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
```

```
const generatePdf = (docDefinition) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const pdfDocGenerator = pdfmake.createPdf(docDefinition);
            pdfDocGenerator.getBase64((pdfData) => {
                resolve({
                    pdfBase64Data: `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdfData}`,
                    onlyData: pdfData,
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {      
            reject(error);
        }
    });
```

Since it works correctly in Android, one can assume that `docDefinition` has the correct value.
I printed the `pdfDocGenerator`  which prints the object appropriately.
Issue is  `pdfDocGenerator.getBase64((pdfData)` never returns and it does not resolve to next level
This happens only in iOS

package.json has below line  `"pdfmake": "^0.2.6",` and i can see it installs 0.2.7 version

Code/project was developed by another team and Now im responsible for continuation of the project. the release version code works perfectly fine in both platform. But I cant make it work in project environment.  Highly doubt on environment set up/ somehow the pdfmake library is not getting bundled in iOS.

- I have tried standalone pdfmake application from the example in mac book, which worked correctly
- I switched older version of pdfmake (0.2.6 and 0.2.4)
- tried below several times

```
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
rm -rf android/app/build
rm ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock 
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
npm install && cd ios && pod update && cd ..
```

- [example link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrt10QogBoU&t=31s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar issue reported in [Github](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/2610). Accordingly changing the pdfmake version 0.1.72 version solved my issue. question is it an ideal way to deal with it!?